# docker-compose - Prisma cannot connect with database (nestjs)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a docker-compose to run back-end and front-end, and database (PostgreSQL) at the same time but when I run it I get this error :

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:44801
api_1       |             reject(new PrismaClientInitializationError(error2.message, this.config.clientVersion, error2.error_code));
api_1       |                    ^
api_1       | 
api_1       | PrismaClientInitializationError: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`
api_1       | 
api_1       | Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.
api_1       |     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:44801:20 {
api_1       |   clientVersion: '3.15.2',
api_1       |   errorCode: 'P1001'
api_1       | }
```

the problem is connecting the application container with database container but how can I fix it?

my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    api:
        build: back-end/
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
            NODE_ENV: development
            PORT: 3000
        ports:
            - "8080:3000"

    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.4
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: db
```

.env inside the back-end folder (this is for connecting nestjs/Prisma with the database):

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db?schema=public"
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `api` is starting up before the database is fully ready; if you run `docker-compose up` in the foreground (without a `-d` option) are there database initialization messages after the Prisma error?  If so, see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to set `networks` on `api` and `postgres` services. It will tell Docker Compose that the should be on the same network and it will allow them to communicate with each other.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
    api:
        build: back-end/
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
            NODE_ENV: development
            PORT: 3000
        ports:
            - "8080:3000"
        networks:
            - my_network

    postgres:
        image: postgres:10.4
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_DB: db
        networks:
            - my_network

networks:
    my_network:
      driver: bridge
```